# Как сделать загрузку на сайт? Как на флеш, там 1,2,3 и т.д. Как загрузилось, сайт плавно появляется

Tags: jquery, html, css

Как сделать загрузку на сайт? Как на флеш, там 1,2,3 и т.д. Как загрузилось, сайт плавно появляется

Comment: Выступлю в роли переводчика, т.к. вопрос тоже интересует:

при заходе на сайт идет загрузка, и отображается показатель загрузки в %. Загружено 6%, 15%.. Как такое реализовать? И обязательно ли на флеше? Прошу напугать примером

p.s. ну а если загрузилось быстро - грузим 1 секунду, для важности )

Answer (score 2):

Можно подумать в эту сторону — http://jsfiddle.net/gydd6/1/show/

Но это очень приблизительно + нет учета фоновых изображения.

Answer (score 0):

1. http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=1257
2. http://adk.am/roman/2012/09/05/27-jquery-css3-krasivyh-resheniy-dlya-animacii-zagruzki-i-indikatorov-progressa.html

Comment: Ещё бы это соотнести с реальным процентажем загрузки страницы